# Парсинг html с помощью jquery ?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Плохо знаю jquery, поэтому хочу узнать как можно получить текст из определенных тегов (идет пять тегов `<p>` - текст нужен из 2, 3 и 4-ого) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, **[взгляните](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/kbdKC/102/)**, подойдет?

Answer (score 0):

можно использовать [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: `html` же заберет html код, а не просто не текст. Попробуйте метод `text()`